# Selecting multiple strings with single dropdown in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am building a Rails app that tracks musicians. I want each user to be able to to select multiple genres they like from a form when they create a profile. I want to store it within the "profile" table for the user in the "genre" column. Right now, I have this, but it only allows me to select ONE option. I want the dropdown to allow multiple options. Is that possible? I'm sure this is very simple.

```
<%= simple_form_for @profile do |f| %>
<%= f.input :genre, collection:['Rock','Blues','Jazz','Classical','Soul','R&B','Alternative', 'Other'], label: "Favorite Genres" %>
```

Right now, genre is a string. Do I need to pass an array? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to do to handle a multi-select with rails.

**1) Allowing the user to select multiple options on the form with the `{:multiple => true}` option.**

```
<%= simple_form_for @profile do |f| %>
<%= f.input :genre, collection:['Rock','Blues','Jazz','Classical','Soul','R&B','Alternative', 'Other'], label: "Favorite Genres", input_html:  {:multiple => true} %>
```

**2) Let your controller accept an array of params for the value.**

```
def profile_params

  params.require(:profile).permit( :years_spent_playing, :user_id, :name, :bio, :age, :city, :state, :primary_instrument, :second_instrument, :third_instrument, :status, :looking_for, :image, :genre => [])

end
```

Im not sure your setup but I get the feeling you may not have the proper models and associations setup to handle this in the ideal way. I would suggest looking at adding a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and breaking your genres out into a separate model and table.

Comment: Might want to use association instead of input: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Comment: @Sixty4Bit I agree. If possible I'd definitely reference an association or query a collection directly instead of hard coding it.  The OP would then have to create a Genre model and store the genre's in the DB. In the controller they'd have to permit the :genre_ids => [] instead of an array of strings.

Comment: Well I tried doing the method with strings, which is what I prefer. I got this error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...es => [], :years_spent_playing, :user_id, :name, :bio, :age,... ... ^ It didn't seem to appreciate the params.require(:profile).permit(:genre => []) part

Comment: Here is my current full params. This gets an error thrown  params.require(:profile).permit(:genres => [], :years_spent_playing, :user_id, :name, :bio, :age, :city, :state, :primary_instrument, :second_instrument, :third_instrument, :status, :looking_for, :image)

Comment: @JSeabolt put :genre => [] as the last param and remove the s in this case to match your input.

Comment: Now rails seems to be upset by the new form tag. It's throwing this error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...'Other'], {:multiple => true} );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^ 

Here is my full link:  <%= f.input :genre, collection: ['Rock','Blues','Jazz','Classical','Soul','R&B','Alternative', 'Other'], {:multiple => true} %>

Comment: Update answer code and added a link to reference materials i hope will help.